# Using jQuery how do I find which row # contains an input with a value in it?

Tags: jquery, select, indexing, html-table, row

I have a table that has multiple rows.  I am trying to return the row # that contains an input which has a value in it.  I understand what I'm doing wrong... my selector is only selecting 1 row, instead of the row # I'm in.  http://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/4Sb8K/

```
   <table id="oustandingItems">
    <tr><th>Category</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="mytest" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="mytest" value="123"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="mytest" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="mytest" /></td></tr>
   </table>


  <button id="findRow">Find Row</button>
  <input type="text" id="myRow" />

$("#findRow").click(function() {   
   var tableRow = $('#oustandingItems tr:has(td input[value!=""])').prevAll().length;  
   $("#myRow").val(tableRow);
});
```

Comment: Can't see your input elem in the table. Can you plz look at the posted fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being the correct solution, only I was using an incorrect jquery version.  This solution works with jquery 1.7.2 and up which is what I tested with.

```
var tableRow = $('#oustandingItems tr:has(td input[value!=""])').prevAll().length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/4Sb8K/

Comment: You sure you don't just want `$('input[value]').closest('tr').index();`?